# OpenGL - translation stretches and distorts sprite

Tags: c++, opengl, transform, translation, distortion

I am loosely following the very handy tutorial at [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org). I've been able to create a mesh, draw a sprite to it, and rotate and scale that mesh perfectly fine.

However, I'm running into some issues when trying to translate the mesh. (pictures below)

Here's an update function on the sprite:

```
    Transform* transform = static_cast<Transform*>(owner->GetComponent(CID_TRANSFORM));

    glUseProgram(shaderID_);

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f , 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(3, 3, 3),
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
        );

    glm::mat4 model = transform->GetModelMatrix();

    glm::mat4 mvp = projection * view * model;

    GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID_, "MVP");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_);
    glUniform1i(samplerID_, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 * 2);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

And here's the getModelMatrix function:

```
glm::mat4 Transform::GetModelMatrix()
{
    glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, translation.x,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, translation.y,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, translation.z,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    float xCos = glm::cos(rotation.x);
    float xSin = glm::sin(rotation.x);
    float yCos = glm::cos(rotation.y);
    float ySin = glm::sin(rotation.y);
    float zCos = glm::cos(rotation.z);
    float zSin = glm::sin(rotation.z);

    glm::mat4 xRotation = glm::mat4(
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, xCos, -xSin, 0.0f,
        0.0f, xSin, xCos, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glm::mat4 yRotation = glm::mat4(
        yCos, 0.0f, ySin, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -ySin, 0.0f, yCos, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glm::mat4 zRotation = glm::mat4(
        zCos, -zSin, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        zSin, zCos, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glm::mat4 rot = xRotation * yRotation * zRotation;

    glm::mat4 sca = glm::mat4(
        scale.x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, scale.y, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, scale.z, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    return trans * rot * sca;
}
```

Here is the sprite at the origin viewed from (3, 3, 3).
[image: first image]

Here is the sprite translated to (1, 0, 0) viewed from (3, 3, 3).
[image: second image]

Comment: The picture does not look distorted to me, just normal perspective projection, just with a large angle of incidence. A part of the rectangle seemed to be clipped by the frustum near field.

Comment: @sevatitov: The camera didn't move between the two pictures, and the only difference is that the mesh was shifted 1 unit along the x axis. In my mind, that would leave the sprite in the same orientation, just moved to the right.

Comment: I think GLM, like OpenGL, uses column major matrices. You're specifying the elements of the translation matrix in row major order.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Ah, silly me! That was indeed it. Thanks! Repost that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching OpenGL, GLM stores matrices in column major order. The constructors also expect elements to be specified in the same order.

However, your translation matrix is specified in row major order:

```
glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, translation.x,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, translation.y,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, translation.z,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

To specify the matrix in the correct column major order, this needs to be:

```
glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    translation.x, translation.y, translation.z, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Typo in first paragraph :)

Comment: Actually, "column major" and "row major" are mixed up here.  In "column major" notation, the translation elements are on the fourth _column_, and in "row major" notation, those elements are on the fourth _row_.

Comment: @PeterO.No, the current version should be correct. The translation elements are always in the last column (well, at least as long as you multiply with column vectors on the right). If the matrix is specified in row major order, that makes them elements 3, 7, and 11. In column major order, they are elements 12, 13, and 14.

Comment: Then the terms "column major" and "row major" should be avoided to prevent confusion.